# How to Install a Delphi 2009 Component Package in Delphi 2010 ( UniSynEdit Package )?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-2010, synedit

I downloaded the SynEdit Unicode Vervion ( UniSynEdit ) , it contains packages of D5-D2009 , but i want to install it in Delphi 2010 ! , I loaded D2009 Package in D2010 IDE , It compiles successfully but there is no Menu item for Installing Package ! :
[image: Picture]

How can i install it in Delphi 2010 ? ( Notice that it compiles successfully )

thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you've got the runtime package.  There should be a separate design-time package, and that's the one you want to install.

Comment: Yes - SynEdit_ **R** 2009 is the **r** untime package, SynEdit_ **D** 2009 is the **d** esign package.

Comment: The question wasn't stupid. These are just conventions that you have to get used to.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that, especially if you're going to use runtime packages. Make a copy of the packages, rename them properly, and then install them. If you use runtime packages and distribute them, the risk is you may overwrite 2009 packages with 2010 ones on someone's system - and they wouldn't be compatible.